# Has there been renewed interest in Cordwainer Smith's stories about chimeras?

Tags: genetic-engineering, instrumentality-of-mankind

Cordwainer Smith's stories about [chimeras](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chimera) (see Definition 4 in this link), i.e., people who were part human and part animal seemed the farthest-out of far-out science fiction when they were first published – at least to me.  I could wave my arms, suspend disbelief and accept faster-than-light-drives and even ETs who were remarkably human in appearance except for their foreheads, but had a much harder time with a person who was partly genetically cat and partly genetically human.

But now, in the light of advancing techniques in microbiology and genetics, it seems likely that chimeras are more possible, technically, (although not socially and hence politically) than FTL drives.

**Thus my question:**  Has there been an upsurge in interest in the work of Cordwainer Smith, manifested by his work being reissued, or by articles written about his work, or sessions devoted to his work at conferences, or whatever?  Moreover, as I recall, chimeras were second class citizens, and I wonder if this attitude has been addressed in any recent — or even old reviews?

Comment: Searches for Cordwainer Smith have dramatically lessened in the last couple of decades; https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=Cordwainer%20Smith

Comment: @Valorum Which is a shame, because everyone should read "[The Ballad of Lost C'Mell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Lost_C%27Mell)".

Comment: @Valorum Thank you for introducing me to Google Trends. I tried several searches (e.g., science fiction, planetary science, Isaac Asimov) and most of them showed the same declining profile as for Cordwainer Smith. Only two (biology, political science) had a different profile, with the low point sagging in the middle, and even they showed larger numbers in 2004 than in recent years. I suspect that Google Trends embeds a systematic error.

Comment: Google Scholar cites 267 works relating to "Cordwainer Smith", of which 25 were published in the 1970s, 33 in the 1980s,  24 in the 1990s, 54 from 2000 to 2009, and 74 in the 2010s. This may indicate a recent surge in interest, though Google Scholar does tend to have a bias toward the present.

Comment: [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Cordwainer+Smith&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCordwainer%20Smith%3B%2Cc0) also shows a nadir in interest in Cordwainer Smith in 2010, followed by a mild upsurge. However, interest in this author seems to have peaked in 1977.

Comment: Cordwainer Smith is underrated. I suspect that part of the reason is his style, which contains elements that are adapted into English from Chinese story-telling style, and which are very alien to the typical English-speaking SF reader.